# Remove backslash ('\') in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I am generating json text and while generating array I get a lot of backslashes I don't need:

```
[\n  
    {\n    
        \"Speed\" : 2,\n    
        \"Direction\" : 3,\n   
         \"OdometerDelta\" : 4,\n    
        \"Longitude\" : 0,\n   
         \"Latitude\" : 1,\n   
         \"TimeStamp\" : \"1996-06-17\"\n  
    },\n 
     {\n   
         \"Speed\" : 2,\n    
        \"Direction\" : 3,\n   
         \"OdometerDelta\" : 4,\n    
        \"Longitude\" : 0,\n   
         \"Latitude\" : 1,\n   
         \"TimeStamp\" : \"1996-06-17\"\n  },\n 
     {\n   
         \"Speed\" : 2,\n   
         \"Direction\" : 3,\n    
        \"OdometerDelta\" : 4,\n    
        \"Longitude\" : 0,\n    
        \"Latitude\" : 1,\n   
         \"TimeStamp\" : \"1996-06-17\"\n 
    }\n

]
```

This is how I get my generated json text NSString:

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Here's the part where things get interesting, if I use

```
jsonString = [jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
```

all of the "\n" is removed (backslash is removed too), but if I use

```
jsonString = [jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];
```

all the backslashes are still there. I am quite new to objective-c so I can't even thought of the possible way of why this happens, I tried several ways, and none of these worked. My shot in the dark is that the problem is caused by encoding but I might be wrong.

Here is how I produce my json file:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {

        NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                         [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.0], @"Longitude",
                                         [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1.0], @"Latitude",
                                         @"1996-06-17", @"TimeStamp",
                                         [NSNumber numberWithDouble:2.0], @"Speed",
                                         [NSNumber numberWithDouble:3.0], @"Direction",
                                         [NSNumber numberWithDouble:4.0], @"OdometerDelta",
                                         nil];


        [arr addObject:jsonDictionary];
    }


    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's important to know what produced the JSON output you posted.  For example it might be something that is adding that escaping for you, in order to make the newlines visible.  So please specify how you got that output.

Comment: Your problem is that you apparently "serialized" the JSON twice.  Fix that, rather than trying to un-muddle things after the deed.

Comment: @trojanfoe Just added code how I produce my JSON.

Comment: I was more interested in knowing how you got the text, rather than the code.  For example was it `NSLog()` or the debugger?

Comment: @HotLicks I can't understand where I serialised second time. Could you explain it more?

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes, I used NSLog

Comment: You didn't shows the NSLog statement.

Comment: (Note that some of the 3rd party "ease of use" HTTP APIs will "automatically" serialize your  JSON for you, so it's important to know how/where you're getting the dump above.)

Comment: (And do note that you're asking for the `\n` codes to be inserted, with NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted.)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I just found a solution.

Comment: @MisterMortal Please post the answer and accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This line

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
```

Gives you a JSON string with line feeds, spaces and indents in to format it prettily when you look at it.  It **does not** put extra line feeds in the data.  If you do this:

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr options:0 error:&error];
```

the JSON string will not have any of those extra formatting characters and will appear to be all one very long line.

Your output that you have posted looks like debug output and those `\n` characters and `\"` characters are escaped by the debug description.  In the actual string, they are proper line feed (character 10) and double quote characters.  This is why your first replace statement works because `@"\n"` is a one character string with just char 10 in it.  In your second statement `@"\\"` is a one character string with a backslash in it and there are no actual backslashes in the JSON string.

Comment: You probably meant "does not put extra *backslashes* ..."

Comment: @MartinR By "the data" I meant in the JSON strings and numbers.  All the linefeeds in the example in the question are just formatting and make no difference to the semantics of the data represented.

Answer (score 0):

```
sonString = [jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
```

will not remove \n it will remove newline characters, which raises the question how are you getting the output you display, is that what really is in the string or is that just information generated on output to show what is a newline character and a quote instead of the end of the string.

Also to remove \" from your string you should really be doing this

```
jsonString = [jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\"" withString:@"\""];
```

otherwise you run the risk of removing \ characters that are suppose to be there.

Comment: I think pursuing this line is incorrect; better is the approach taken by @HotLicks in the comments, where preventing the escaping in the first place is better than removing them afterwards.

Comment: Removing \n isn't the problem here. My problem is that 'stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString' is not working in my case, I tried the thing you just suggested and it didn't worked.

Comment: @MisterMortal - Replacing strings containing `\\` with stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString is very tricky.  It can be done but requires careful consideration of the scenario.