# Alamofire: Adding extra forward slash to unicode character

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, unicode-string

I'm getting response from server and converting this response to NSDicitonary. My code is as following:

```
Alamofire.request("MyURL", method: .post, parameters:attributes, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: [:]).responseJSON {
            response in                

            switch response.result {
            case .success:

                let swiftyJsonVar = response.result.value!
                do {
                    if let dicObj = swiftyJsonVar as? NSDictionary {
                        print(dicObj)
```

But my issue is, one of my key having unicode character `\u{20b9}` and when I convert it to NSDictionary from response.result.value then it add one more slash to unicode character like `\\u{20b9}`.

Comment: The \ character must be backslash escaped. A `NSString` of \ is encoded as the JSON string \\.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609224/remove-backslash-in-objective-c) if it can help you. And this comment `Your problem is that you apparently "serialized" the JSON twice. Fix that, rather than trying to un-muddle things after the deed.`

Comment: Probably [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16948785/1140335) will solve your issue.

Comment: No Success :( .